# Group values and get percentage from database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, percentage

I have a database table where I save players bets it the following logic:

[image]

This table will of course have several **user_id's** for every **match_id**. I want to display how the users have placed their bets. If they think that the home team will win lose or draw. AND I want it to be stated in percentage.

> Germany - France 35% - 20% - 45%.

So far I have managed to calculate the quantity guesses, but not the percentage,  with the following query:

```
SELECT games.home_team,games.away_team,COUNT(*) as 'qty',user_result_bet.match_id,(
CASE
WHEN `home_score` > `away_score` THEN 'home'
WHEN `home_score` < `away_score` THEN 'away'
ELSE 'draw'
END) as 'tipped_result'
FROM user_result_bet,GAMES
WHERE games.match_id = user_result_bet.match_id
GROUP BY tipped_result, match_id
ORDER BY match_id
```

Where do I go from here? I want to turn this in to percentage somehow? Im using PHP for the website

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use count if

```
SELECT user_result_bet.match_id,COUNT(*) as 'qty',

count(if(`home_score` > `away_score`,1,null))/count(*)*100 as home_percent,
count(if(`home_score` < `away_score`,1,null))/count(*)*100 as away_percent,
count(if(`home_score` = `away_score`,1,null))/count(*)*100 as draw_percent
from wherever
group by 1
```

Comment: You think about a problem for a month, then you post it here and you get an answer (correct one as-well) in 5 minutes. Thank you! :)

Comment: that was my first experience when I started using stack as well :)

Answer (score 0):

```
SUM(CASE WHEN `home_score` > `away_score` THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)/COUNT(*) AS PercentageHome
```